# Laravel 5: check if user arrived at a page via url or back()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to know if there is a way to find out if the user is hitting the page via URL or as a result of then `back()` method. this is what I mean:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $request->session()->flash('message_error', trans('messages.errors'));
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

There is a piece of logic I have to perform only when the user is hitting the page by a link or URL, but never when he's hitting as a result of the `return back()`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Add a session variable via AJAX  on the back button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flash additional data with the `back()` function, i.e.:

```php
return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator)->with('back', true);
```

Then in your view/controller you can check the session, i.e.:

```php
if (session()->has('back')){
    // your logic here
}
```